Conditional rendering based on a boolean value in React JS
I'm working with a JavaScript object and I'm trying to render a button based on a boolean value, but I'm running into an issue. Here's a snippet of my code:
const toy_material = toy.material.allow; // This is a boolean value that can be true, false, undefined, or null
console.log("toy_material", toy_material);

When I console.log("toy_material", toy_material), nothing is showing up in the console. I'm also trying to conditionally render a button based on the value of toy_material. I want the button to show regardless of whether toy_material is true, false, undefined, or null.
How can I achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried logging the value using console.log("toy_material", toy_material); but nothing is printing in the console. I'm expecting it to log the value whether it's true, false, undefined, or null, so I can use that value to conditionally render a button. I want the button to render in all cases, regardless of what the boolean value is. How do I achieve this?

Your code snippet is not enough to determine what could be going wrong with your code. More information is needed to be able to help with your problem.

You should consider using optional chaining to check if the properties you are trying to access are being returned first; then, depending on the response, you can proceed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

first use ? operator with object properties which help manage null, undefiend
const toy_material = toy?.material?.allow;
in order to render the button if toy_material is true it shows button else in case of null, undefined, and false nothing will shown. here is how you can do it.
return (
  <div>
   { toy_material && <button>click here!</button> }
  </div>
)

I Hope it works for you.

They stated that they want the button to be shown regardless of the value of toy_material. This won't achieve that. Regardless, we're lacking info.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
